# How to send information to another page with SSL in Opencart

Tags: php, email, ssl, ssl-certificate, opencart2.x

So I have created a custom form page that accepts applications from potential employees.

It worked fine before I added an ssl certificate but now is not sending any of the data along with the email.

It will send the Template email but not the data but I know that the data is making it to the controller.php as the sender in the Email is correct.

I bring the info into the controller as follows.

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
if (isset($this->error['fullname'])) {
$data['error_fullname'] = $this->error['fullname'];
} else {
$data['error_fullname'] = '';
}
```

Then send the data to my employment template where I believe the issue is

```
  $html = $this->load->view('default/template/mail/employment.tpl',$data);
// This right here no Longer works after adding SSL
```

Then send the mail after attaching the HTML

```
$mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['fullname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')); 
$mail->setHtml($html);
$mail->send();
```

This is located out side of the POST if statement to makesure the action on the form is using SQL

```
$data['action'] = $this->url->link('information/Employment', '', 'SSL');
```

Then in employment.tpl my email Template I will reference fullname

```
<?php echo $fullname ?>
```

I always receive the email but it is only the template never any of the data. I have tried using the full link with https:// on the `$this->load->view` but that does not work either.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated and will be glad to provide any additional information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the ssh setting is working fine or not on your site.

system -> settings -> store edit and then check SSH setting.

it is just issue of the http => https or https => http

Please communicate on skype if not resolved.
skype: jks0586

Comment: If you mean SSL it is checked and working properly. Also the Data should be https => https.

Comment: Kindly provide me site URL where data is not posting.